# problem in redirecting in guarded route - Vue js Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this route in my vue router.js file .

```
routes: [{
      path: "/",
      component: Home,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!store.state.is_login) {
          next('/login')
        }
        next()
      }
    }]
```

I use beforeEnter option for redirecting user if  **store.state.is_login** **=== true**

first problem :
so when I enter the url in browser I will redirect to /login page. this is works fine. but when I click the logo button, this **beforeEnter** function is not working.
this is my button that uses :

```
<router-link to="/" class="bp-logo"><Logo />home</router-link>
```

the second problem is :

1. is_login is in my store.state.is_login
2. I am storing my token in the localStorage
3. user_info is in store.state.user

problem :

condition 1: if !is_login redirect to /login .

condition 2 : if token exists and !is_login =>  request to backend  /user with token and get user_info and set is_login true.

condition 3 : if !is_login && !token redirect to /login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out somehow. the first problem was when you render a route .then you are click for getting to that route again the function router.beforeEach not trigger. so I find another method in documentation.

```
routes: [{
      path: "/",
      component: Home,
      beforeEnter: isAuthenticated,
    }]
```

and this is my custom function for handling both problems .

```
const isAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.state.is_login) {
    if ((localStorage.getItem('token')) && (lodash.isEmpty(store.state.user))) {
      let headers = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
      };
      axios
        .get(`${store.state.api}admin/user`, headers)
        .then(response => {
          store.state.user = response.data.user;
          store.state.is_login = true;
          next("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          store.state.Error = error;
          next('/login')
        });
    }
    next('/login')
    return
  }
  next()
  return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `beforeEnter` method to access the store instance. Rewrite like this:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!this.$store.state.is_login) {
          next('/login')
        }
        next()
      }
```

Comment: tnx for reply but my problem is not that . I imported store .!this.$store.state.is_login is undefined

Comment: Ahh, it's undefined because you haven't declared the store in your `main.js`. Didn't realize you were doing a local import. What errors are you getting in the console, if any?

Comment: tnx your answer was very helpfull.